# Create vector of the culmative counts per level

Tags: r

I have lots of little vectors like this:

```
 id<-c(2,2,5,2,1,9,4,4,3,9,5,5)
```

and I want to create another vector of the same length that has the cumulative number of occurrences of each id thus far. For the above example data this would look like:

```
> id.count
 [1] 1 2 1 3 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 3
```

I can not find a function that does this easily, maybe because I do not really know how to fully articulate in words what it is that I actually want (hence the slightly awkward question title). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
ave(id,id,FUN=seq_along)
```

Gives:

```
 [1] 1 2 1 3 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
> sapply(1:length(id), function(i) sum(id[1:i] == id[i]))
 [1] 1 2 1 3 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 3
```

Or if you have `NA`s in `id` you should use `id[1:i] %in% id[i]` instead.